# How can I replace all occurences of symbols that do not appear in a predefined string/list?

Tags: python, function

So I am trying to make a function where a user is asked for a text to input and the result should print an encrypted version of the text.

The way it should work is that all symbols not matching any symbol in
this variable:

```
alphabet =  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ?"
```

should be replaced with a question mark `'?'`.

So for example:

```
'THIS is a t#est'
```

would result in

```
'???? is a t?est'.
```

This is what I got so far.

```
alphabet =  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ?"

xalphabet = list(alphabet)

code = input('Please enter the text you want to code: ')

xcode = list(code)

def clean_text(xcode):
    for xcode in xalphabet:
        if xcode == xalphabet:
            continue
        else:
            xcode.replace(xcode, '?')

    return xcode

def main ():
    print(clean_text(xcode))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What I got only prints `'?'`

Comment: Seem to be a few confused elements in here, like looping through xalphabet with a variable called xcode, which is also the variable you passed into your function. also the comparison is more likely to be `if x in xalphabet...`

Comment: I guess you need `if xcode in xalphabet:` instead of `if xcode == xalphabet:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just iterate through your string with a list comprehension, then use `''.join`:

```
alphabet =  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ?"

s = 'THIS is a t#est'

>>> ''.join([i if i in alphabet else '?' for i in s])
# '???? is a t?est'
```

Or as a function:

```
def clean_text(xcode):
    return ''.join([i if i in alphabet else '?' for i in xcode])
```

As a different approach, you can think about using a regex:

```
import re
s = 'THIS is a t#est'

>>> re.sub('[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ?]', '?',s)
# '???? is a t?est'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn your code to a working code with this:

```
alphabet =  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ?"

code = input('Please enter the text you want to code: ')

def clean_text(code):
    for x in code:
        if x not in alphabet:
            code = code.replace(x, '?')
    return code

print(clean_text(code))
```